# Add columns based on join

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have huge tables (*3 millions records*) that must have a joined column. This value will not change.

How can I **add** a column based on a join? There will be some other queries. If I use join, it will be a slower process.

Ex:

Main Table:

```
add_cod | name
 1      | alfa
 2      | beta
 1      | zeta
```

Addon Table:

```
cod | col_ext
 1  | jam
 2  | bam
```

The result should be the main table, but with col_ext column:

```
add_cod | name | col_ext
 1      | alfa |   jam
 2      | beta |   bam
 1      | zeta |   jam
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple `JOIN`.

```
SELECT  a.*, b.col_ext
FROM    main a
        INNER JOIN addon b
            ON a.add_cod = b.cod
```

You don't have to worry about performance if you have properly implemented index on your tables.

## [SQLFiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/eb66f/2)

Answer (score 2):

You will use a `JOIN`:

```
select m.add_cod,
  m.name,
  a.col_ext
from main m
left join addon a
  on m.add_cod = a.cod
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34aa6/1)

If you need help understanding joins, here is a great [visual explanation of joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)